# Receiving 0x00 from Telnet in Python

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

Im using Python 2.7 with`telnetlib`, but I'm unable to receive 0x00 byte.

If I send 4 bytes "abcd", I receive all 4 of them. But if the two middle bytes are 0x00, as in "a  d", using read_some() I only get "ad". Why are the other two bytes being ignored?

Comment: Can you provide your source code?

Comment: The code is onlt a couple of lines, like ``data = port.read_some()`` and then iterate through data and print it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python reading until null character from Telnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136109/python-reading-until-null-character-from-telnet)